# Custom MessageBodyReader not found in JerseyTest

Tags: rest, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am having a bizarre problem with my JerseyTest class.

When executing my test code and putting a break point on line 203 of [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.4/jersey/jersey-common/xref/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/ReaderInterceptorExecutor.html), I see that my reader is not in reader.workers.  However, as you can see below, I register this MessageBodyReader in the ResourceConfig.

All relevant code is provided below.

## My custom MessageBodyReader/Writer

```
@Provider
@Produces({V1_JSON})
@Consumes({V1_JSON})
public class JsonMessageBodyHandlerV1
    implements
      MessageBodyWriter<Object>,
      MessageBodyReader<Object> {
  ...
}
```

And yes, `isReadable` returns **true**.

When debugging, I see that the code hits `writeTo` but *not* `readFrom`.

## Test code that fails

```
public class TestLocationResource extends JerseyTest {

  public static class LocationResourceHK2Binder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      // Singleton bindings.
      bindAsContract(LocationDao.class).in(Singleton.class);

      // Singleton instance bindings.
      bind(new FakeLocationDao()).to(LocationDao.class);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void basicTest() {

    LocationListV1 actualResponse = /**/
    /**/target(LocationResourceV1.PathFields.PATH_ROOT)
    /*   */.path(LocationResourceV1.PathFields.SUBPATH_LIST)
    /*   */.request(V1_JSON)
    /*   */.header(HEADER_API_KEY, "abcdefg")
    /*   */.get(LocationListV1.class);

    assertEquals(10, actualResponse.getLocations().size());
  }

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
    enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

    ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
    rc.registerClasses(LocationResourceV1.class, JsonMessageBodyHandlerV1.class);
    rc.register(new LocationResourceHK2Binder());

    return rc;
  }
}
```

(Pulling from [this example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/tests/e2e/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/tests/e2e/server/CustomInjectablesResourceConfigTest.java).)

## The resource it's testing...

```
public class LocationResourceV1 implements ILocationResourceV1 {
  ...

  @Inject
  private LocationDao daoLoc;

  private final LocationTranslator translator = new LocationTranslator();

  @Override
  public LocationListV1 listV1(String apiKey) {
    return translator.translate(daoLoc.query(LocationFilters.SELECT_ALL));
  }

  ...

  @VisibleForTesting
  public void setLocationDao(LocationDao dao) {
    this.daoLoc = dao;
  }
}
```

(Note that the web service annotations such as @GET are in the interface.)

## Generates this fail trace

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyReader not found for media
>   type=application/vnd.com.company-v1+json, type=class
>   com.company.rest.v1.resources.location.json.LocationListV1,
>   genericType=class
>   com.company.rest.v1.resources.location.json.LocationListV1.
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:207)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1109)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:851)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:96)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:761)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:396)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:296)
>     at
>   com.company.rest.resources.location.TestLocationResource.basicTest(TestLocationResource.java:47)
>   [...]

## ... with this console output

```
[...]
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Oct 29, 2013 4:26:16 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
1 > GET http://localhost:9998/location/list
1 > Accept: application/vnd.com.company-v1+json
1 > X-ApiKey: abcdefg

Oct 29, 2013 3:30:21 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.company.persistence.dao.intf.LocationDao] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.company.persistence.dao.intf.LocationDao class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:189)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:159)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:125)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:176)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:649)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:604)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:396)
    [...]
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.company.persistence.dao.intf.LocationDao
    contracts={com.company.persistence.dao.intf.LocationDao}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@568bf3ec
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=143
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=2117810007
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:615)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1916)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$700(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:113)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:993)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$6.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:988)
    [...]
    [...]
    (Above is repeated 4 times)
    [...]
    [...]
```

## Followed by this, implying that there was a successful response

```
Oct 29, 2013 3:30:22 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
2 < 200
2 < Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 22:30:21 GMT
2 < Content-Length: 16
2 < Content-Type: application/vnd.com.company-v1+json
{"locations":[]}

Oct 29, 2013 3:30:22 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer stop
INFO: Stopping GrizzlyTestContainer...
Oct 29, 2013 3:30:22 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener stop
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
```

Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this looks like a Jersey bug.  When I do `client().register(JsonMessageBodyHandlerV1.class);` outside of `configure()` (such as within a `@Test` or in a custom `@Before`), it works.  Still don't know how to get rid of those spammy 'Could not find a suitable constructor' error messages though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first stack-trace comes from your client because you didn't register your message-body provider there (and hence it cannot be found). [JerseyTest#configure](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.html#configure%28%29) method is supposed to be used to configure only the server-side. There is another method called [JerseyTest#configureClient](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.html#configureClient%28org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig%29) intended to be used on the client-side. You need to override both methods if you want to use a custom provider.

The second stack-trace comes from your `LocationResourceHK2Binder`. By

```
bindAsContract(LocationDao.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

you're telling HK2 that `LocationDao` class should be instantiated as a singleton and HK2 would then inject it to `LocationDao` types. You may want to change your binder to use something like:

```
bind(new FakeLocationDao()).to(LocationDao.class);
```

For more information on this topic, refer to [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html).

Comment: Thanks Michal, I was not aware of configureClient.  As far as your binder comment, this -- `bind(new FakeLocationDao()).to(LocationDao.class).in(Singleton.class)` is not possible by their API since the first `bind(T service)` returns a `ScopedBindingBuilder` which does not allow you to specify a contract (the `in`.)  The way I have it set up "works" but it just spams exceptions within the console warning messages.  I looked through the link you provided and wasn't able to see how to resolve this issue.

Comment: That said, `bind(mockedDaoInstance).to(LocationDao.class).to(new TypeLiteral<Singleton>() {});` has the same effect as the above.

Comment: Oh $h, I was wrong.  I was running the whole test suite and was still seeing the exceptions -- stupid me.  The line in my comment above worked.  Thank you, sir :)

Comment: Right, removed `.in(...)` call. When you bind an instance it is in Singleton scope by definition. Mea culpa.